# Downloading a file with file name greater than 255 characters using MS edge

Tags: java, windows-10, microsoft-edge, long-filenames

I am using the spring framework to serve a file for download. I have the following code.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>>
            defExport()
                    throws IllegalStateException,
                    IOException {
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        int status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        List<Integer> byteList = Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            File file = transformService.executeExport(something);
            byte[] fileContent = null;
            try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                fileContent = read(is);
            }
            String fileName = StringUtils.join(something, ".xlsx");
            headers.add("fileName", fileName);
            headers.add("Content-Disposition", StringUtils.join(
                    "attachment; filename=\"", URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF8"), "\""));
            for (byte b : fileContent) {
                byteList.add(new Integer(b));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = STATUS_ERROR;
        }
        headers.add("ifxResultStatus", String.valueOf(status));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(byteList, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

on JS side, I have the follwing:

```
_self.xhr.open('POST', targetUrl, true);
        _self.xhr.onreadystatechange = goog.bind(this.blankDlResponseHandler, this);
        _self.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', project.core.app.View.getCsrfToken());
        var form_data = new FormData();
        _self.xhr.send(form_data);
```

When I try to download the file with name greater than 255 characters, I can do so successfully in Chrome and IE11 on Windows 10.

However, when I try to do so in MS Edge, the download is unsuccessful due to the long file name. 
How can I make it work on MS Edge also.

## Edit

I just realized that in Chrome the file name is always limited to 218 characters and the last characters are trimmed.

So, my new question is how can I limit the characters to 218, specially in the case where a file with the same name already exists (file names are then appended (1),(2) and so on)

Comment: At what windows location you are downloading the file ?

Comment: In the Downloads folder